# Select all option for checkboxes wont change after save

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a select all option that is also a checkbox for a group of checkboxes. It works well, except:

if you click select all

then save

open the form and uncheck a few checkboxes individually

then save again

open the form again

all the checkboxes will still be checked.

As long as you don't use the select all option the checkboxes save normally.

I think it has something to do with the hidden fields included by rails, but I'm not sure how to get around that.

```
  $('#select_all').change ->
    $('.avail-to-order').prop 'checked', $(this).prop('checked')

  $('.avail-to-order').change ->
    if $(this).prop('checked') == false
      $('#select_all').prop 'checked', false
    if $('.avail-to-order:checked').length == $('.avail-to-order').length
      $('#select_all').prop 'checked', true


<%= f.check_box :id, { class: 'avail-to-order', checked: id_checked}, id, 0 %>
```

Comment: I didn't include the code involved with saving the form because there's nothing noteworthy about it. It's just the usual. This form saved fine until I introduced the "select all" functionality.

Comment: If you submit a form, the page is reloaded. Is that your issue? Sorry but for me it is quite unclear what you are asking BUT i could be just too tired...

Comment: I edited the sequence of events a bit. Hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: I'm not a rail guy but maybe that's because you don't trigger change event on checkboxes when using the check all one. Does it make any difference: `$('#select_all').change ->
    $('.avail-to-order').prop 'checked', $(this).prop('checked').trigger('change')` ?  EDIT: sorry, surely this is a synthax error but the idea is once you have change the state using prop, trigger change event. Like i said, i don't know the synthax to use here, my bad

Comment: What does the log look like for the actions you're describing?